# Launcher and panel missing [ubuntu 13.04]

Tags: unity, launcher, 13.04, gconf

When I booted my laptop to ubuntu 13.04 today the panel and launcher were both missing from the screen and I had no idea how to get them back.

Using a ubuntu 13.04 install medium I formatted `/` and installed the system again leaving my `/home` intact.
When I logged in to my user account the problem persisted.
The unity-greeter is displayed perfectly fine and the guest account has no problems either.

I was eventually able to get the launcher and panel back by deleting `.config/` `.gconf/` `.local/` and `.cache/` but when I restarted my laptop the problem was back.

Do you have any suggestions for me? The last thing I tried earlier was `unity --reset`
but I got an error message telling me that it's deprecated.

Comment: A few days ago this [solution][1] was posted. Seems to be a problem wiht Compiz.

[1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/286444#286444