# ubuntu 13.10 no launcher and no dash appears

Tags: unity, 13.10, launcher, unity-dash

I've the same issue in the question here.

- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
- [Launcher and panel missing [ubuntu 13.04]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288235/launcher-and-panel-missing-ubuntu-13-04/289498#289498)

It might be a duplicate question.
But none of these answers work in ubuntu 13.10

Do anyone have any ideas to fix this issue in 13.10 ? I can't do anything with my computer now... thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + ALT + F2 and login to a text session by typing your username and password. After you sign in type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wget python dconf-tools
wget https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb
sudo chmod +x unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
unity-reset
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
compiz --replace
sudo reboot
```

Don't worry if you get an error after compiz --replace. That's just in there for good measure.